# Simple delete query. What is the best index?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, sql-delete

We are deleting a large number of rows in a table as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29103752/deleting-a-large-number-of-records-using-pl-sql/29104176) using the following SQL:

```
 DELETE FROM MYTABLE
               WHERE     UPDT_TIMESTMP < v_Cut_Off_Date
                     AND ROWNUM <= C_MAX_DELETE;
```

It has come to my attention that the UPDT_TIMESTMP can be NULL. This field stored the TIMESTAMP value of when the record was last updated *after* the initial create. Therefore, I am looking to modify my SQL to consider the CREATE TIME if the Update time is NULL.

```
 DELETE FROM MYTABLE
               WHERE     NVL(UPDT_TIMESTMP, CRET_TIMESTMP) < v_Cut_Off_Date
                     AND ROWNUM <= C_MAX_DELETE;
```

My preference would have been to disallow NULLs and to update set the value of the UPDT_TIMESTMP column to the CRET_TIMESTMP value, but this is not an option.

Since the table was going to be large, about 20M records a month and every month I would be deleting a month's worth of old data, I wanted to make sure that I could quickly locate the records to delete.

Using this *original* SQL,

```
DELETE FROM COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL
      WHERE UPDT_TIMESTMP < SYSDATE AND ROWNUM <= C_MAX_DELETE;
```

...with no indexes, this was the query plan using Toad for Oracle:

```
Plan
DELETE STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 2  Bytes: 41  Cardinality: 1            
    3 DELETE FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL        
        2 COUNT STOPKEY     
            1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL Cost: 2  Bytes: 41  Cardinality: 1
```

Added an index over Last Update Time:

```
CREATE INDEX FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL_UPDTM ON FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL
(UPDT_TIMESTMP)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE USERS
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
NOPARALLEL;
```

Query Plan after adding indexed on Last Update Time (index is used)

```
Plan
DELETE STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 0  Bytes: 41  Cardinality: 1            
    3 DELETE FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL        
        2 COUNT STOPKEY     
            1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL_UPDTM Cost: 0  Bytes: 41  Cardinality: 1
```

Modified Query to use Creation date if Update Time is NULL

```
DELETE FROM COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL
      WHERE NVL(UPDT_TIMESTMP, CRET_TIMESTMP) < SYSDATE AND ROWNUM <= C_MAX_DELETE;
```

Added separate index over Create Time

```
CREATE INDEX FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL_CRET ON 
FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL
(CRET_TIMESTMP)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE USERS
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
NOPARALLEL;
```

Checked Query plan after 2 seperate indexes were added.

```
DELETE STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 2  Bytes: 54  Cardinality: 1            
    3 DELETE FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL        
        2 COUNT STOPKEY     
            1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL Cost: 2  Bytes: 54  Cardinality: 1
```

QUESTION: **Why was neither index used?**

Added a new index with both LAST UPDATE and CREATE TIME columns in the same index

```
CREATE INDEX FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL_UPDCRT ON FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL
(UPDT_TIMESTMP, CRET_TIMESTMP)
LOGGING
TABLESPACE USERS
PCTFREE    10
INITRANS   2
MAXTRANS   255
STORAGE    (
            MAXSIZE          UNLIMITED
            PCTINCREASE      0
            BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
            FLASH_CACHE      DEFAULT
            CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT
           )
NOPARALLEL;
```

**Still, no index was used. Why?**

```
Plan
DELETE STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 2  Bytes: 54  Cardinality: 1            
    3 DELETE FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL        
        2 COUNT STOPKEY     
            1 TABLE ACCESS FULL TABLE FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL Cost: 2  Bytes: 54  Cardinality: 1
```

I realize that not having very much data in the table can effect the Explain Plan (I have very little.) Must I generate millions of rows to get a real idea of what to expect or can I get a general idea without doing that?

**Why are the indexes not being used in the examples above or am I misreading the plans?**

**Update:**

When I take Mat's sugegstion to break up the DELETE into two updates, the first by CREATION date:

```
DELETE FROM COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL
      WHERE UPDT_TIMESTMP  < SYSDATE AND ROWNUM <= variable;
```

...the index over UPDATE DATE is used for the first

```
Plan
DELETE STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 0  Bytes: 54  Cardinality: 1            
    3 DELETE FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL        
        2 COUNT STOPKEY     
            1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL_UPDCRT Cost: 0  Bytes: 54  Cardinality: 1
```

And for the second SQL...

```
DELETE FROM COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL
      WHERE UPDT_TIMESTMP IS NULL AND  CRET_TIMESTMP < SYSDATE AND ROWNUM <= Variable;
```

The index with both columns is used:

```
Plan

DELETE STATEMENT  ALL_ROWSCost: 0  Bytes: 54  Cardinality: 1            
    3 DELETE FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL        
        2 COUNT STOPKEY     
            1 INDEX RANGE SCAN INDEX FIN_IT_RPT.COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL_UPDCRT Cost: 0  Bytes: 54  Cardinality: 1
```

Comment: Have you considered creating a function-based index on `NVL(UPDT_TIMESTMP, CRET_TIMESTMP)` ?

Comment: Did you re-analyze the table after adding each index (e.g. `BEGIN DBMS_STATS.ANALYZE_TABLE('FIN_IT_RPT','COMMRCL_CORE_CLM_DTL'); END;`)? After making any structural change to a table it should be re-analyzed to ensure that the statistical information needed for the optimizer to do its job properly are available. Best of luck.

Comment: @Bob: I'm new to Oracle. I ran your sugegsted code and got this: PLS-00302: component 'ANALYZE_TABLE' must be declared. Intellisense (Copde completion shows me many methods in that package but not that one.) I am using Oracle 11g.

Comment: @David: I haven' heard of that, but that sounds interesting.

Comment: It's `GATHER_TABLE_STATS`, not `ANALYZE_TABLE`. Low tech solution: do two deletes, one based on update date, one on update is null and create date.

Comment: @Mat: Thanks, 'ANALYZE_TABLE' worked, but the results were the same. See my update regarding splitting up the delete  into two statements. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @Mat: so much for **my** memory... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use separate DELETE statement without NVL for the 2nd case:

```
DELETE FROM MYTABLE
           WHERE     UPDT_TIMESTMP IS NULL AND CRET_TIMESTMP < v_Cut_Off_Date
                 AND ROWNUM <= C_MAX_DELETE;
```

you can merge both statements to one with `... WHERE UPDT_TIMESTMP < v_Cut_Off_Date OR (UPDT_TIMESTMP IS NULL AND CRET_TIMESTMP < v_Cut_Off_Date) ...`

if you have only few records with `UPDT_TIMESTMP IS NULL`, create a function based index with `MY_NVL(UPDT_TIMESTMP,CRET_TIMESTMP)` where the function `MY_NVL` returns CRET_TIMESTMP for UPDT_TIMESTMP IS NULL and NULL for UPDT_TIMESTMP IS NOT NULL, then the where condition would look like `... WHERE UPDT_TIMESTMP < v_Cut_Off_Date OR MY_NVL(UPDT_TIMESTMP,CRET_TIMESTMP) < v_Cut_Off_Date ...`

you can also try a function based index with `NVL(UPDT_TIMESTMP, CRET_TIMESTMP)`  (as originally David proposed - sorry David, I haven't read your comment)

Comment: Regarding the merged SQL, shouldn't the query plan be the same for that as using the NVL function?

Comment: no because when you use the NVL without function based index then you cannot use the indexes on the columns used as parameters (therefore FULL TABLE SCAN)

Comment: See my comment immediately above yours. I am wondering why using the NVL function as I original suggested and you echoed results in a table scan but splitting it up as Pavel suggested uses the index over (UPDATE TIME, CREAT TIME).

Comment: as I already wrote, to index a function result you have to define a function based index, indexing the function parameters only will cause FULL TABLE SCAN